# UICollectionView: Is there a way to reload only the decoration views?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uikit

Is there a way to only reload decoration views of UICollectionView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't, but you can reload the section which will also reload the headers/footers

```
 snapshot.reloadSections(snapshot.sectionIdentifiers)
```